# When to use Ajax vs Json for Javascript events?

Tags: ajax, json

I'm not so familiar with Ajax but I keep hearing Json mentioned as some kind of competing option. Is there a rule for when to use one versus the other?

I'd like to process Javascript events in my app and update the front-end dynamically from the app but I'm not sure whether I need to use Ajax or Json for this.

Comment: just because this is googleable doesn't mean it's a bad question

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: it's a bad question not because it's googleable, but because explaining difference between oranges and aeroplanes are rather hard if not impossible and is very close to being meaningless.

Comment: Then this question will help set them straight. Besides, we want SO to appear in Google..

Comment: Technically, Ajax with JSON should be called Ajaj or (AJ)², shouldn't it? :D

Comment: Actually, this is hard to google, not easy because it's difficult to get a direct explanation of the difference. I would argue this is a great question, albeit a pretty specific misunderstanding.

Comment: googling "ajax" and "json" is hard? Wikipedia alone is quite clear about what each is and isn't.

Comment: @OrgeonGhost: I'm inclined to think that AJAX is well understood to not necessarily be XML or even asynchronous already. I'd rather not see another acronym in the world myself.

Comment: I actually talk about it as xhr with my team, not ajax, but ajax is certainly more understood ... and more fun to say.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's some JSON:

```
{ "taco" : "awesome", "burrito": "less awesome", "fishTaco": "1000" }
```

Looks pretty much like an array in this case.

And you can use AJAX to get the JSON.  I use it to return table data often. You've probably already used JSON-like data in your javascript but didn't realize it.

I prefer to request JSON data rather than XML or HTML.  I find it easier to deal with than XML, and more flexible than HTML.

Comment: Strange that I've got two down votes on this, what did I miss?

Comment: I think you did not answer the question. is like saying "i like xml" and question is "when to use it".

Comment: Hmm ... I think you didn't read the question very well.  He asked when to use JSON v. when to use AJAX.  The question doesn't make sense. There was clearly some confusion about the two technologies that I aimed to clarify.

Comment: Incorrect Json. Correct is: { "taco": "awesome", "burrito": "less awesome", "fishTaco": 1000 }
All strings must be quoted, with double quotes.

Comment: I would say looks more like an object than an array ;)

Answer (score 32):

[Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and [JSON](http://json.org/) are very different things.

From [Ajax (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)):

> Ajax, sometimes written as AJAX
>   (shorthand for asynchronous JavaScript
>   and XML), is a group of interrelated
>   web development techniques used on the
>   client-side to create interactive web
>   applications or rich Internet
>   applications. With Ajax, web
>   applications can retrieve data from
>   the server asynchronously in the
>   background without interfering with
>   the display and behavior of the
>   existing page. The use of Ajax has led
>   to an increase in interactive
>   animation on web pages and
>   better quality of Web services thanks
>   to the asynchronous mode. Data is
>   retrieved using the XMLHttpRequest
>   object. Despite the name, the use of
>   JavaScript and XML is not actually
>   required, nor do the requests need to
>   be asynchronous.

From [Introducing JSON](http://json.org/):

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange language.

Comment: You beat me to it.  Same links even.

Answer (score 13):

JSON is not a competing technology to AJAX it's just a data format.

Where you might hear competition is between XML and JSON, JSON having the advantage of being typically lighter and in native javascript already, XML having the advantage of portability and toolsets.

---

[Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 9):

As some have stated, these are two different things entirely. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax%5F%28programming%29) is a method of using JavaScript to initiate HTTP requests to fetch data. That data can be in any sort of format, but most commonly XML, HTML, and yes, JSON.

So, as already mentioned, [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) is a data format much like XML or CSV, just with a different set of formatting rules.

Answer (score 7):

Json is nothing more (and nothing less) than a format of the data you transfer with the Ajax-way of talking to the server.

Some transfer the data in the form of xml, other just plain text, others use Json.

More info about JSON on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json

Answer (score 4):

Ajax and JSON aren't the same thing. Ajax is a technique combining, among other things, lightweight asynchronous requests and typically some DOM manipulation, in order to create richer user interfaces in web applications.

The "X" in Ajax is often taken to mean "XML", and many sites using Ajax use XML as the format of the data returned by the server in response to such requests.

JSON ([http://json.org](http://json.org/)) is a lightweight data interchange format based on Javascript's object notation. As such, it's easy to parse in Javascript. It's also a lot less verbose and repetitive than XML.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be talking about AJAX vs JSONP

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#JSONP

If that's the case, the one benefit of using JSONP, is that you can get around the cross-site sandboxing (although, possibly introducing new security risks)

Answer (score 3):

AJAX is used for get data from server, whereas JSON is just a data format which can used to send data to the server.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would provide this comparison from my class lecture

```
AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript + XML) incorporates several technologies:
```

- Standards-based presentation using XHTML and CSS;
- Dynamic display and interaction using the Document Object Model (DOM);
- Data interchange and manipulation using XML and XSLT;
- Asynchronous data retrieval using XMLHttpRequest;
- JavaScript binding everything together.

> JSON, short for JavaScript Object Notation is a lightweight data interchange format. Its main application is in AJAX web application programming, where it serves as an alternative to the use of the XML format for data exchange between client and server.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct, but If you are new to using web technologies, all you need to know is simply 
that Ajax is a subset of JavaScript.
It is a technology, a means for you to send only portion of the web page data back to the server to get processed 
and get the response back while the user is interacting with other parts of the page.  This way, the
Interaction with the page is consistent and  seemless from the user stand point.   Now, JSON on the other hand is 
the how you can format the data (similar to XML) that you are sending back to the server, and getting back.
and it's used primarily with Ajax.  It was developed and used mainly 
because it is lightweight and human readable,  which makes it more efficient and user friendly.
Hope that helps a bit.